# adding conditional prompt to Cognos 10 sql based query

Tags: sql, prompt, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Cognos BI version: 10.2.2 using report studio
I have a report with one prompt p1 and its a sql query based report.
Prompt UI:
p1 is a DropdownList(use value, display value) 
1-All, 2-value2, 3-value3, 4-value3

I am trying to add condition based prompt syntax the sql query..

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1
where col4  is not null
case when #Prompt('p1')# = 1 then ' and 1=1'
     when #Prompt('p1')# = 2 then ' and col1 is null and col2 is not null'
     when #Prompt('p1')# = 3 then ' and col1 is not null and col2 is null'
     when #Prompt('p1')# = 4 then ' and col1 is null and col2 is null'
end
```

I tried to use lot of syntax searching online but couldn't find the examples with respect to my scenario. I need help in achieving the correct way of writing the statements to satisfy my requirement.any help is appreciated..

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: sorry. I tried to use lot of syntax searching online but couldnt find the examples with respect to mine. I need help in achieving the correct way of writing the statements to satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I suggest you post the error but this one seems obvious

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1
where col4  is not null
and (
(#Prompt('p1','token','0')# = 1) OR
(#Prompt('p1','token','0')# = 2 and col1 is null and col2 is not null) OR
(#Prompt('p1','token','0')# = 3 and col1 is not null and col2 is null) OR
(#Prompt('p1','token','0')# = 4 and col1 is null and col2 is null)
)
```

Comment: I did some online search. Came across the below macro syntax which is helpful. #prompt(‘name’,’datatype’,’default’,’pretext’,’source’,’posttext’)#. I tried to plug in to my code and am trying to do this #Prompt('p1','string','1',' and 1=1')#  and it gives me RQP-DEF--177 error sqlprepareoptions status = 9.. It's very confusing the syntax..

Comment: I've altered the answer - this should make the prompts optional. Yes the syntax is extremely confusing!